# Is it possible to reverse WordPress thumbnail box resizing?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, thumbnails, image-resizing

An example: say you have set the thumbnail size in WordPress to `200px/200px` without cropping. If you upload an image that is `600px/300px` it will be resized to `200px/100px`. In other words it is resized to fit within the defined thumbnail dimensions, similar to the CSS `background-size: contain;` property.

What I'd actually like is to shrink the uploaded image as much as possible to *fill* the defined thumbnail, similar to the CSS `background-size: cover;` property. So my `600px/300px` image would be resized to `400px/200px`.

I don't want to implement a CSS fix for this; I'm hoping to find a solution I can implement in WordPress so that my images are actually resized as I've described. I'm currently defining two alternative thumbnail sizes and them comparing them before outputting them, but I'd prefer to have a solution that doesn't require the extra image files. The code I'm using works like this:

```
add_image_size('thumbnail_wide', 0, 250, false);
add_image_size('thumbnail_tall', 250, 0, false);
```

and later:

```
$thumbnail_tall = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail_tall');
$thumbnail_wide = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail_wide');

if ($thumbnail_wide[1] >= 200 && $thumbnail_wide[2] >= 200) {
  $attachment_data['thumbnail'] = $thumbnail_wide;
} else {
  $attachment_data['thumbnail'] = $thumbnail_tall;
}
```

Comment: Would passing a custom size array into `wp_get_attachment_image_src` not work? That will return a cropped image of the specified size which I am guessing is what you want.